# Active Directory. Two questions. Purpose of permissions and program to test AD

Tags: active-directory

I'm new to AD and I'm learning with some books.

I have two questions, being the first question the most important.

1) I have created an users OU under my DC. I created some test users. I can assign each users permissions to read an write. The questions is: read or write what? the users are used to logon to some domain, so the user can read what kind of thing? and what can read, the list inside the OU? the user can ask AD to retrieve the user list inside this OU? can modify other users configuration? What's is the purpose of the reading and writing.
Can you point me how this matter is called in the Windows world.

2) I want to read a directory listing. Do I need some kind of client? or inside a Windows PC I can ask or the directory loading some hidden Windows program?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `I want to read a directory listing.` - Do you mean you want to query the active directory database?  It is LDAP.  You can use your favorite ldap client, or library.

Answer (score 3):

> I can assign each users permissions to read an write. The questions
>   is: read or write what?

Those permissions are applicable to whatever object the permissions are applied to. If they're applied to a folder, they can read or write to that folder. If they're applied to a file, they can read or write that file. If they're applied to an AD object, they can read and/or write that AD object.

> I want to read a directory listing. Do I need some kind of client?

They can use ADUC, just like you are. They'll only be able to see objects they have permissions to see, and modify objects they have permissions to modify.

Answer (score 1):

> I can assign each users permissions to read an write. The questions is: read or write what

The suggestion of EEAA about your first question is correct. Read more about user permissions on Windows Technet website in order to understand how it works.

> I want to read a directory listing. Do I need some kind of client?

Regarding your second question, you can always use the **dcdiag** (Directory Server Diagnosis)  command on either Command Prompt or Windows Powershell which will show you the current status of your Active Directory.